# pip install missed setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py

I create a very simple python project include empty `foo.py` and `setup.py`:

```
setup( # ...
    name='any_name',
    version='1.4',
    py_modules=['foo']
# ...
)
```

Then distribute it to my local pypi repo (Nexus): `$ python setup.py sdist upload -r mypypi`.
There is a `setup.py` in the zip file on the repo.
And install to my current folder: `$ pip install --target=. any_name`.
There are no `setup.py` in the installed folder.
I want `setup.py` must be in the installed folder. Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit why you want `setup.py` to be available in your installed folder? This file is only required to install a package, not to run it.

Comment: I want to distribute my source include all code in `setup.py`.

Answer (score 1):

**edited**: I completely revised my answer to make things easier (I hope).

`setup.py` is not required to be installed, it's only required to install the package. By default, when a distribution is created based on a `setup.py`, it already includes several files and/or directories (e.g. modules referenced in `packages` parameter of ´setup(...)`,`setup.py`,`*.txt` files, and so on). A complete list of files that are automatically bundled in a distribution can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute

If you need to specify other files or directories that should be part of your distribution, you can either define the `package_data` and/or `data_files` parameters when calling `setup(...)`. See ttps://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-installing-package-data for more information about the expected format of `package_data` and `data_files`.

You can also define a `MANIFEST.in` file to list all the files and directories that need to be part of your distribution. By default, all the files that are listed in `package_data` and `data_files` will be automatically appended to the ones listed in `MANIFEST.in`.

Notice that all the files defined in `MANIFEST.in` will be part of your distribution, but not necessarily included when your package is installed. For what I understood from Python packaging documentation:
 - Files listed in `package_data` and `data_files` will be automatically copied upon installation;
 - Files listed in `MANIFEST.in` will be copied **only** if `include_package_data` parameter to `setup(...)` is set to `True`.

However, please note that files listed in `package_data` are **only** included in your installation if you're not using `sdist` (i.e. only for binary distribution). As a consequence, it's safer to always rely on `MANIFEST.in` combined with `include_package_data=True`.

Comment: And if you simply put `setup.py` in `MANIFEST.in`?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to create a `myfile.txt` in root package then `include *.txt`. Those files were added to .zip file on repo but those are not in installed folder.

Comment: What about `package_data` and `data_files` parameters for `setup(...)`? (see https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-installing-package-data). I didn't see you wanted to create an sdist.

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify the way you can bundle files to your package, at "distribution creation" time and at installation time. In your case, I think a simple `include_package_data=True` will do the trick, as `setup.py` is automatically added to the manifest of your package by setuptools.